# Website Loads CSS / Jquery styles slowly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website i'm designing right now, and i'm new to using JQuery. I'm noticing on my slick-carousel slider that the slides and styles adjust them self's while the user is loading the page for the first time in the browser. I have a few media-queries in place for different resolutions, and it seems that it has to adjust.

Is this because of the way i wrote the code, or is this something that happens with Javascript? What's the best practice to avoid this?

Here is the site link - [Advanced Litho Website Re-design](http://www.advancedlitho.com)

Comment: Can you post a small example showing us the problem? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Try minifying your css and js scripts. Images shouldn't be ridiculous in size either (not sure if they are).

Comment: You can probably define a `width` and `height` for the images inside that carousel, so it doesn't jump around as images are being loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this URL: https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.advancedlitho.com/aCuNhAl7

Here you can see that your images are huge in size. GTMetrix is showing that scaling your images properly can give you a boost of 1.9MB

Do whatever is said on the test and you should be fine.